# How can I debug Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm 99% sure something is going on with my `hxs.select` on this website. I cannot extract anything. When I run the following code, I don't get any error feedback. `title` or `link` doesn't get populated. Any help?

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class=\'footer\']')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = CarrierItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('.//a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('.//a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Is there a way I can debug this? I also tried to use the `scrapy shell` command with an url but when I input `view(response)` in the shell it simply returns `True` and a text file opens instead of my Web Browser.

```
>>> response.url
'https://qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/login.jsp'

>>> hxs.select('//div')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

>>> view(response)
True

>>> hxs.select('//body')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Comment: The site isn't loading at all for me. What does `response.body` look like?

Comment: You can always include `print sites` and see what is printed during crawling.

Comment: This site is our intranet so you won't have access to it. if i type in response.body i do get back the xml-stylesheet (i could not post the whole thing too many characters) >>> response.body
'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
 \n        <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/dis/xslt/htmlpage.xslt"?>\n
  \n    <page hide-loading="true">\n    <title>Login</title>\n    \n    <head>\n
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dis/css/login.css"> </link
>

Comment: I added print sites to my code but nothing happen the only difference I saw in the cmd prompt was it had an empty brackets []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy shell is a good tool for that indeed. And if your document has an XML stylesheet, it's probably an XML document. So you can use scrapy shell with `xxs` instead of `hxs` as in this Scrapy documentation example about removing namespaces:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#removing-namespaces

When that doesn't work, I tend to go back to pure lxml.etree and dump the whole document's elements:

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

class myspider(BaseSpider):
    ...
    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")
        root = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.body).getroot()
        # or for broken XML docs:
        # root = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.body, parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True)).getroot()
        # or for HTML:
        # root = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.body, parser=lxml.html.HTMLParser()).getroot()

        # and then lookup what are the actual elements I can select
        print list(root.iter()) # this could be very big, but at least you all what's inside, the element tags and namespaces
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pdb from the command line and add a breakpoint in your file. But it might involve some steps.

(It may differ slightly for windows debugging)

1. Locate your `scrapy` executable:

   ```
   $ whereis scrapy
   /usr/local/bin/scrapy
   ```
2. Call it as python script and start pdb

   ```
   $ python -m pdb /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl quotes
   ```
3. Once in the debugger shell, open another shell instance and locate the path to your spider script (residing in your spider project)

   ```
   $ realpath path/to/your/spider.py
   /absolute/spider/file/path.py
   ```

This will output the absolute path. Copy it to your clipboard.

4. In the pdb shell type:

   ```
   b /absolute/spider/file/path.py:line_number
   ```

...where line number is the desired point to break when debugging that file.

5. Hit `c` in the debugger...

Now go do some PythonFu :)

Answer (score 1):

## Using VSCode:

### 1. Locate where your scrapy executable is:

```
$ which scrapy
/Users/whatever/tutorial/tutorial/env/bin/scrapy
```

For me it was at `/Users/whatever/tutorial/tutorial/env/bin/scrapy`, copy that path.

### 2. Create a launch.json file

Go to the debug tab in VSCode and click "Add configuration"
[image]

### 3. Paste the following template into the launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "args": ["crawl", "NAME_OF_SPIDER"],
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "PATH_TO_SCRAPY_FILE",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

In that template replace `NAME_OF_SPIDER` with the name of your spider (in my case `datasets`). And `PATH_TO_SCRAPY_FILE` with the output which you got in step 1. (in my case `/Users/whatever/tutorial/tutorial/env/bin/scrapy`).
[image]

### 4. Check that VSCode was opened at the root of your scrapy project

### 5. Set a breakpoint and click debug!

Answer (score 0):

To use pdb to debug a scrapy spider, you need to insert a debugging point and include some code to make turn it on and off:

[This is a very simple spider.](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/scrapy-tutorial-5-how-create-simple-scrapy-spider/)

To make this spider debuggable with pdb, you can add the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

import os
import pdb

class QuotesSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'simple'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def __init__(self):
        scrapyDebug = os.getenv("SCRAPY_DEBUG")
        if scrapyDebug and int(scrapyDebug):
            pdb.set_trace()

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']//span[@class='text']/text()").extract()
        yield {'quotes': quotes}
```

So running the spider normally doesn't invoke the debugger. If you have a bug you need to de-, you invoke the debugger like this:

```
SCRAPY_DEBUG=1 scrapy crawl simple
```

In the spider **init**() method the debugger will be started. You can then set breakpoints in places in the code where you've had issues.